# Solve $z + z^{-1} = x$ with elementary methods

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the equation$$z + z^{-1} = x\tag{1}$$ with elementary methods. 
I know the two solutions to be $$x_{1}=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-4}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x_{2}=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-4}\text{.}$$

Of course knowing all the solutions suffices to proof equation (1) by direct calculation, showing that $x_{1},x_{2}$ satisfy eq. (1). This boils down recognizing that $x_{1}^{-1} = x_{2}$. One can bring eq. (1) in this form if one expands x by either $x_{1}$ or $x_{2}$. But how can I solve eq. (1) by direct calculation? Are there any elementary arguments which lead to the solution or do I have to resort to *guessing* the correct solutions and show that the solve eq. (1)? Maybe some connection to parameterizations of a circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying throughout by $z$, we ned up with a quadratic
$$z^2 + 1 = xz \implies z^2 - xz + 1 = 0 \implies \left(z-\dfrac{x}2\right)^2 = \dfrac{x^2-4}4\implies z = \dfrac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2-4}}2$$

Comment: Nice answer. To address OP's other question, I note that in the original equation 
$$
z + z^{-1} = x
$$
if we set $u = z^{-1}$, we get
$$
u^{-1} + u = x
$$
which we can rewrite as
$$
u + u^{-1} = x
$$
so that if $z$ is a solution, $z^{-1}$ must also be a solution. As you noted, this boils down to noting that $x_1^{-1} = x_2$. But my point is that you can know that for any solution, its inverse is also a solution, without first finding the solutions. 

I mention this because the group of symmetries of the solution set to an equation can sometimes be useful in hunting for a solution.

Comment: Thanks you two, it was embarrassingly easy.